# Perform scroll handler only on certain screen sizes

Tags: javascript

Appreciate this is a pretty basic question... I'm just having real trouble!

I have this currently working:

```
// SHRINK HEADER
window.onscroll = function() { 
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.padding = "1.5rem 0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.padding = "3rem 0";
  }
}
```

I am trying to implement the following, to make the function only execute above a certain screen size:

```
if (screen.width > 991){
  // do stuff
}
```

I've tried wrapping the former in the latter, but I think I'm approaching it from a HTML point of view, javascript is a bit above my pay grade!

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just FYI, your code had nothing to do with jQuery so I've edited the title and tags

Comment: Thanks Rory, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CSS3 media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to hide the y-overflow beneath a certain threshold.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
// SHRINK HEADER
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
function scrollFunction() {
if (window.innerWidth < 991) {
  document.getElementById("nav").style.padding = "1.5rem 0";
}
else if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
  document.getElementById("nav").style.padding = "1.5rem 0";
} else {
  document.getElementById("nav").style.padding = "3rem 0";
}
}
```